# jQuery ajax and character encoding

Tags: php, ajax, encoding

I'm using this code to get some html content from a php page:

```
$.ajax({
   url:server+'/getMessage/40',
   cache: false,
   success: function(res) {
       var text = res.responseText;
       $('#result').html(res);
    }
});
```

The text is retrieved from the db.

The php file looks like this:

```
$app->get('/app/get/getMessage/:Id',function ($Id='') use ($app) {
$msgElements = 'Title,Body';
$msgFe = $conn->query("SELECT $msgElements FROM messages WHERE Id='".$Id."'");
    $fields = explode(',',$msgElements);
    while($msgData = $conn->extract($msgFe)){
        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $arr->$field = $msgData->$field;
        }
    }
    $ele=' <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>'.$arr->Title.'</hi>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                '.$arr->Body.'
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
            ';
    echo $ele;
});
```

If I place the browser the the location of the php page, with the proper `GET` instructions, I get the text without any problem. However, if I retrieve the text with the above ajax function, it shows the `?`s...

From my tests (and other threads here on SO) I'm assuming the problem relies somewhere in the ajax function... Any help?

PS I've noticed that if I try to use `json_encode()` on the text that contains characters that are not properly visualized the result is `null`. I hope i helps!

Comment: Did you try to add the header("charset=utf-8") in the beginning of the php?

Comment: The response headers of your AJAX response may need to reflect what's inside the db.

Comment: @Jack, how do I do that?

Comment: @ghego1 `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=latin1');` ... no guarantees though.

Comment: @Jack thank's! However I just realized that only the collation is in latin swedish, the actual data I think is in UTF8. Which makes me even more confused on the reason this is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `utf8_encode()` your values from your database because the resulting value is not utf8 encoded as you said.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't solve the problem... (and so I've deleted it from the code)

Comment: Are you sure your page is utf8 encoded and do you have a meta that sets the charset to utf8?

Comment: In the `head` of the document in which js should place the html I have `<meta charset="utf-8">`, so I guess yes, but I'm not really sure...

Comment: You were right!!! I was simply utf8_encoding in the wrong way, so that wasn't working... I've corrected the way I'm encoding and now it works, thank's!!